# AT command stop with serialport nodejs

Tags: node.js, gsm

262/5000
Hello, I am trying to send SMS via nodejs and a USB dongle that works as a modem, but when I execute a command it gets blocked and does not execute the rest, but when I remove the command I get the SMS but the text of the message with the AT command, HELP!

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var port = new SerialPort("COM5", {
 baudRate: 9600,
 dataBits: 8,
 parity: 'none',
 stopBits: 1,
 flowControl: false});
 port.on("open", onOpen);
 port.on('error', onError);
 port.on('data', onDataReceived);

function onOpen(error) {
 if(!error){
    console.log('Port open sucessfully');
        send(port, "XXXX", "BAL");
        //read(port);
 }
}

function onDataReceived(data){
console.log("Received data: " + data);}

function send(serial, toAddress, message) {
serial.write("AT+CMGF=1"); //This command stopped script
serial.write('\r');
serial.write("AT+CMGS=\"" + toAddress + "\""); //send sms but the text included AT COMMAND
serial.write('\r');
serial.write(message);
serial.write(Buffer([0x1A]));
serial.write('^z');}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. This is probably due to needing to delay things a bit